# Adjusting the y-axis range in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need some help in Matlab. I have to implement the Newton Method and plot the function `f` and some approximations of the method. I used the following code:

```
plot(x,f(x))
hold on
for j=1:4
    x_1=x_0-f(x_0)/F(x_0);
    l=@(x) (f(x_0)/(x_0-x_1))*(x-x_1);
    plot(x_0,f(x_0),x,l(x),x_1,0)
    x_0=x_1;   
end
```

Is this correct? When I plot it, the range of y-axis is [-2000, 30000]. How can I change it? How can I make it smaller so that I can see the result better?

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])
```

you can set the axis limits to whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

To just change the y-axis, have a look at [`ylim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html):

```
ylim([ymin ymax])
```

Similarly, there is an `xlim` command.  By default, these will be in `auto` mode (i.e. `ylim('auto')` and `xlim('auto')`) so that when you change the range of the x-axis, the y-axis range will automatically change to an appropriate range for the visible data.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep track of the smallest and largest "interesting" values of x by adding

```
xMin = min(x0, xMin);
xMax = max(x0, xMax);
```

In you loop (after appropriately initializing `xMin` and `xMax`) - then changing the x axis with:

```
xlim([xMin xMax]):
```

As was pointed out, if you leave the other axis alone it will scale by itself. You could change things by increasing or decreasing the range, for example

```
delta = xMax - xMin;
xlim([xMin - 0.2*delta xMax + 0.2*delta)];
```